# Linking error when subclassing QChartView

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to override the mouseMoveEvent method by subclassing ChartView and I get a linking error which has something to do with the constructor of ChartView class.

```
class ChartView : public QChartView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ChartView(QChart* chart, QWidget* parent = 0);

protected:

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;

};

ChartView::ChartView(QChart* chart, QWidget* parent)
    : QChartView(chart, parent)
{
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
}

void ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << event->pos();
}
```

The error:

1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl ChartView::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@ChartView@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl ChartView::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@ChartView@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)

1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl ChartView::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@ChartView@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

When I remove the constructor of ChartView, the problem is gone, but I dont know why, because I also dont understand the error.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Run qmake again and every time your add `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before building your application, you need to clean qmake and run it again. Then, you can rebuild the solution. Problem is fixed.